# What is the difference between JS files in dist/ folder and the one in root?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am totally new to NodeJS and I wonder what's the difference between those two.

For example, in this project (https://github.com/fikriauliya/hipku), we have `index.js` and `dist/hipku.js`. They are similar except the last line:

`module.exports = publicMethods;` vs `return publicMethods;`

I guess `dist/hipku.js` is generated from `index.js`? How is it generated and why does it need to be generated?

Comment: From the readme: "Install with `npm install hipku` or use a browser-ready file in the `dist` folder." As for how they are generated, there aren't any build scripts in the repository, so possibly manually.

Comment: I fork that project and wish to modify a bit. Ideally, how should my workflow is? I guess index.js is the one I need to modify? Then, how should I generate the ones in dist?

Comment: Tough to say since they didn't provide a contributions document. You could create an issue on the repository, asking the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you want to use this package, in browser or server side.

- server side

`index.js` is the entry of NPM package. When you do `require('hipku')`, actually NodeJS locates the file module `node_modules/hipku` and run `index.js` ends up with the object adhere to `module.exports`

- browser

Just load `dist/hipku.js` into your browser by `<script>`, it will register `hipku` into your global namespace, then you can use it's API.

Answer (score 2):

Things in the dist folder are usually the product of building from index.js in this case. You'll notice it gets minified, and that folder would eventually be used on production sites. If you look at the package.json file, you'll notice that index.js is the main file, so if you're doing any edits, that would be the place to do so.

Comment: What tools are widely used to generate the files in dist folder?